# Crawl an AJAX page with Goutte in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler, goutte, domcrawler

I'm trying to crawl an AJAX website with [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte), and the Symfony Dom Crawler to get some articles for our online shop. I get the error:

> Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE

The address is http://b2b.asicsonline.com/adg/welcome

I can't get the form or log me on the site. Could you tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Can we see the code you have so far? There appear to be three `<form>` elements on the page, but very little renders in a browser without JavaScript. Do you have login credentials for this page? Even with JS it appears to require authorisation.

Comment: Goutte has no js engine, try to use Selenium or casperjs.